# How to rebuild ign-msgs for gazebo9?

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've install gazebo9 on a Bionic machine which has more up to date versions of protobuf than gazebo is expecting. Specifically, the apt package for `ign-msgs1` was compiled with something before protobuf 3. So naturally, I'm trying to rebuild `ign-msgs1` so that it will be up to date. However, this fails because there are macros in ign-msgs1 `Utils.cmake` which are defined by `ign-cmake0` in `IgnUtils.cmake`. This conflict makes it impossible to rebuild `ign-msgs1` on Bionic.

I can't upgrade from `ign-msgs1` without recompiling everything else, so I'm wondering if there's a way to make `ign-msgs` use its own macros instead of getting them stomped on by `ign-cmake0`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24296/how-to-rebuild-ign-msgs-for-gazebo9?/) by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 768 on 2020-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The solution here was to build protobuf 3.0.0 from source. The ubuntu package installed 3.8.0 because I was using a Lambda Labs machine which requires 3.8.0 for some other packages

Luckily, it's incredibly easy. Install protobuf 3.0.0 (from github releases for example) using the `cmake` install process (not the make process!). In protobuf, go to the `cmake` subdirectory and do the usual

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

Then if you're building with cmake, just make sure you either 1) append /usr/local to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr` when building proto.

For me, this process installed `/usr/local/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-config.cmake`, which could be found by catkin (or normal cmake) without messing with system protobuf 3.8.0

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2020-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> I'm trying to rebuild ign-msgs1 so that it will be up to date.

There might be a way to get this to work, but I wouldn't recommend it. Proto 3's API is not backwards compatible with Proto 2 (for example, no more optional fields). You can install Proto 2 and 3 side-by-side. Since `ign-msgs1` and `gazebo9` depend on Proto 2, I recommend you install and use that.

> there are macros in ign-msgs1 Utils.cmake which are defined by ign-cmake0 in IgnUtils.cmake

I don't see a `Utils.cmake` on `ign-msgs1`. All its cmake macros should be coming from `ign-cmake0`. What are the conflicting macros you're seeing?

> I'm wondering if there's a way to make ign-msgs use its own macros instead of getting them stomped on by ign-cmake0

We created `ign-cmake` so it could hold macros to be reused by all other Ignition libraries. So it's expected that the macros are coming from that package.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2020-01-15**:
Do you have any experience with proto2 being installed alongside proto3? I'm not sure it would work nicely because they have the same fundamental library names. I'll try it though.

Here are the conflicting macros: https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-msgs/src/ignition-msgs1_1.0.0/cmake/Utils.cmake

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-01-15**:
Interesting, that file doesn't exist on `ign-msgs1`: https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-msgs/src/ign-msgs1/cmake/Utils.cmake, maybe you can try updating to the latest release branch. I haven't investigated much, but Gazebo 9 seems to be linking against libprotobuf 3.0.0, but still using `proto2` message syntax. So I guess maybe 2 versions can't be co-installed, but version 3 supports syntax 2.

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2020-01-15**:
I just noticed that and I'm confused -- if gazebo uses libprotobuf3, why am I getting compiler errors: `/usr/include/ignition/msgs1/ignition/msgs/time.pb.h` This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2020-01-15**:
The failing check is `3000000 < GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION` so it would seem that the ign-msgs1 headers were generated with protoc 2? Is that true?